# Jboss ,Infinispan, How to configure Jboss As managed cache manager

Tags: java, caching, jboss, infinispan

I am trying to use `Jboss AS` managed `Infinispan` in my application, so that I can use `Jboss Admin console` to manage it.
I have tried the following steps based on Infinispan documentation,

1) Created a class named Config

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager;

public class Config {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/test")
    private EmbeddedCacheManager defaultCacheManager;

    public void printObject() {
        System.out.println("defaultCacheManager:" + defaultCacheManager);
    }
}
```

2) created a servlet just for making Config object and calling printObject() method

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** 
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3200037917839533696L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doIt(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doIt(req, resp);
    }

    protected void doIt(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Config config = new Config();
            config.printObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

3) Added the application dependencies via standalone.xml global configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">  
        <global-modules>  

            <module name="org.infinispan" slot="main"/>  
            <module name="javax.enterprise.api" slot="main"/>  
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>  
            <module name="javax.inject.api" slot="main"/>  
            <module name="javax.annotation.api" slot="main"/>  
        </global-modules>  
</subsystem>
```

4)Added new cache container in subsystem named test

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="test">  
        <cache-container name="test" default-cache="entity" start="EAGER">  
            <local-cache name="entity"/>  
        </cache-container>  
</subsystem>
```

5)Removed all Infinispan related jars from my application

But, When I try to call the printObject() method from servel it is printing **null**

13:37:24,206 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1) **defaultCacheManager:null**

Why it is happening , please correct me if any thing is missed from my side.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. It's working for me and I am using it in my running application also. Let me know if there is any issue or you require some modification as per your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/test")
private EmbeddedCacheManager defaultCacheManager;
```

Or

Here is a sample code:

**Config.java:**

Its defined as managed bean that is initialized at the time of server start-up and its default constructor is called where its reference is stored in a static field to access it from anywhere in the application.

Config class must be as singleton. Do not call `new Config()` any where in code. It is created by server itself.

Call `Config.getInstance()` whenever it is needed in the application.

It also handle the condition where configuration is missing (on dev machine).

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.CacheMode;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer;
import org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager;

@ManagedBean(name = "Config", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

    @Resource(name = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/test")
    private CacheContainer container;

    private Cache<String, Object> entityCache = null;

    private static Config configInstance = null;

    public Config() {
        configInstance = this;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        entityCache = container.getCache("entity");
    }

    public static Config getInstance() {
        if (configInstance == null) {
            createInstance();
        }
        return configInstance;
    }

    public Cache<String, Object> getEntityCache() {
        return entityCache;
    }

    private static void createInstance() {
        configInstance = new Config();

        if (configInstance.container == null) {
            ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            confBuilder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL);

            EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(confBuilder.build());
            cacheManager.start();

            configInstance.container = cacheManager;
        }
        configInstance.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank  you. I have tried your answer and is working. But I can see you are using the Jsf for this. I am new this annotation stuffs, so I am doing some studies regarding this. Also I am not getting why the example given in Infinispan documentation http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_use_a_jboss_as_7_configured_cache is not wroking. Let me study more about this Mbean concepts and after that I will update on this.

Comment: Great, Finally its working for you. Actually I am also using this stub in my running application and it working perfectly. Good Luck...